# How I can assign the result of a query to multiple variables at once without use a cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

When I need to store the result of a SQL sentence in a variable I can use a code like so

```
declare @Max as int
set @Max=(select max(field_name) from table_name)
```

But now i wondering if is possible do the same for multiple variables for example for a sentence like

```
select max(field_name), min(field_name) from table_name
```

how i can store the result in two variables called  @Max and @Min?

I know which this can be done using cursors

```
DECLARE @Max as int, @Min as int
DECLARE cursor_minmax CURSOR FOR
Select max(field_name), min(field_name) from table_name
OPEN cursor_minmax 
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_minmax  INTO @Max,@Min
CLOSE cursor_minmax 
DEALLOCATE cursor_minmax
```

but i want to know if is possible assign that values wihout use cursors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this as:

```
select @max =  max(field_name), @min = min(field_name)
from table_name
```

I see . . . your confusion is that you want to use "set".  You can only set one value with "set".  You can set as many values as you like with "select".

Answer (score 0):

```
Select @Max = max(field_name), @Min = min(field_name) from table_name
```

Or am I missing some understanding of what you are asking?